# write entry to array shorthand

Tags: java, java-8

Im new to java and I’ve the following code , is there an efficient way to write it using java8:

```
List<String> apps = new ArrayList<>();

for (ApplicationSummary applicationSummary : appSumList) {
    apps.add(appList.getName());
}

return apps;
```

Comment: `apps.add(appList.getName());` shouldn't this be `applicationSummary.add(appList.getName());`

Comment: What is `appList`? and you are using a for-each loop but not using the `applicationSummary` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
appSumList
  .stream()
  .map(ApplicationSummary::getName)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Uncertain to know if this is ok right now. The OP is using `appList.getName()` so we don't know if `ApplicationSummary` has a `getName` and if is that what the OP wants.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I thin that is a typo on OP side

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you want to add all `name` properties of your `ApplicationSummary` objects to the `apps` `List`.

Something like:

```
apps
    // adding all to "apps"
    .addAll(
        // streaming list of "ApplicationSummary" items
        appSumList.stream()
        // mapping item to its name
        .map(ApplicationSummary::getName)
        // collecting as List (which is what will be passed to addAll)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()
    )
);`
```

**Edit**

As [Juan Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7694740/juan-carlos-mendoza) points out, you might not need to invoke `addAll` on your `apps` `List` if you *only* want to contain the `name` properties of each of your `appSumList` elements:

```
// assigning value to "apps"
apps = 
    // streaming list of "ApplicationSummary" items
    appSumList.stream()
    // mapping item to its name
    .map(ApplicationSummary::getName)
    // collecting as List
    .collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Comment: Why using `addAll` instead of a direct asign to `apps`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza good point. I just "assumed" that `apps` might contain something else as well. There are a lot of assumptions in play here to be honest...